# How to add a bottom border in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to add a bottom border to my tabs. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(
      image: UIImage(named: "Twitter")!.resize(25, 25)
    )
    
    let leftBarImage = UIImageView(
      image: UIImage(named: "Profile")!.resize(35, 35)
    )
    leftBarImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
    leftBarImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray4.cgColor
    leftBarImage.layer.cornerRadius = leftBarImage.frame.width / 2
    leftBarImage.clipsToBounds = true
    
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
      customView: leftBarImage
    )
    
    let segmentedControl = UIStackView()
    segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    segmentedControl.axis = .horizontal
    segmentedControl.alignment = .center
    segmentedControl.distribution = .fillEqually
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .green
    segmentedControl.addBorder(
      for: .Bottom,
      color: UIColor.red.cgColor,
      thickness: 20
    )
      
    for menuLabelText in ["For you", "Following"] {
      let menuLabel = UILabel()
      menuLabel.text = menuLabelText
      menuLabel.textAlignment = .center
      menuLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
      
      segmentedControl.addArrangedSubview(menuLabel)
    }
    
    self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
      segmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor)
    ])
  }
}
```

And the border logic,

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    enum BorderSide {
        case Left, Right, Top, Bottom
    }

    func addBorder(for side: BorderSide, color: CGColor, thickness: CGFloat) {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color

        switch side {
          case .Left:
            border.frame = CGRect(
              x: frame.minX,
              y: frame.minY,
              width: thickness,
              height: frame.height
            )
            break
          case .Right:
            border.frame = CGRect(
              x: frame.maxX,
              y: frame.minY,
              width: thickness,
              height: frame.height
            )
            break
          case .Top:
            border.frame = CGRect(
              x: frame.minX,
              y: frame.minY,
              width: frame.width,
              height: thickness
            )
            break
          case .Bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(
              x: frame.minX,
              y: frame.maxY,
              width: frame.width,
              height: thickness
            )
            break
        }

        layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

The border is not showing at all. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

You can see the green background but not the red border beneath. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do not capitalize enum case names.

Comment: Please read http://www.programmingios.net/premature-layout/

Comment: @matt Can you please explain why is so?

Comment: I think you'll find that's the problem. `viewDidLoad` is the wrong moment to position a layer.

Comment: @matt I see. Thanks for the resource. I'm indeed new to iOS app development. That article should definitely be helping me.

Comment: Also you are forgetting to subtract the thickness so you can easily end up with the whole border layer outside the view.

Comment: Finally (sorry) I really strongly recommend not using UIStackView for this. It just adds unknown mysterious behavior. Just construct the interface and its constraints yourself.

Comment: @matt Hey man I'm all ears. I would love to hear every advise you got. By "Just construct the interface", did you mean to create two ui labels and constraint them using autolayout? And what kinda "mysterious behavior" are we talking bout?

Comment: Also where can I learn more about constructing layouts efficiently? Can you please guide me to a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at what's wrong with the code...

The `addBorder(...)` func in your `UIView` extension uses the view's `frame` -- so, let's put a `print()` statement right before we try to add the border, to see the the view's frame:

```
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .green
    
    // print the frame of segmentedControl to debug console
    print("segmentedControl Frame in viewDidLoad():", segmentedControl.frame)
    
    segmentedControl.addBorder(
        for: .Bottom,
        color: UIColor.red.cgColor,
        thickness: 20
    )
```

You will see this in the debug console:

```
segmentedControl Frame in viewDidLoad(): (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

So your extension tries to set the frame of the layer:

```
border.frame = CGRect(
    x: frame.minX,       // minX == 0
    y: frame.maxY,       // maxY == 0
    width: frame.width,  // width == 0
    height: thickness.   // thickness == 20 (passed in call)
)
```

As we see, we end up with a layer frame of `(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.0, height: 20.0)` ... we won't see anything, because it has no width.

So, let's try adding the border in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Note that we'll move the `segmentedControl` creation outside of `viewDidLoad()` so we can reference it elsewhere. And, we'll leave the `addBorder()` with **red** where it was, then call it again with **blue** in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // create it here, so we can reference it outside of viewDidLoad()
    let segmentedControl = UIStackView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        self.title = "Bad Layout"
        
        segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        segmentedControl.axis = .horizontal
        segmentedControl.alignment = .center
        segmentedControl.distribution = .fillEqually
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .green
        
        // print the frame of segmentedControl to debug console
        print("segmentedControl Frame in viewDidLoad():", segmentedControl.frame)
        
        segmentedControl.addBorder(
            for: .Bottom,
            color: UIColor.red.cgColor,
            thickness: 20
        )
        
        for menuLabelText in ["For you", "Following"] {
            let menuLabel = UILabel()
            menuLabel.text = menuLabelText
            menuLabel.textAlignment = .center
            menuLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
            
            segmentedControl.addArrangedSubview(menuLabel)
        }
        
        self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            segmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor)
        ])
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // print the frame of segmentedControl to debug console
        print("segmentedControl Frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews():", segmentedControl.frame)
        
        segmentedControl.addBorder(
            for: .Bottom,
            color: UIColor.blue.cgColor,
            thickness: 20
        )
    }
}

extension UIView {
    enum BorderSide {
        case Left, Right, Top, Bottom
    }
    
    func addBorder(for side: BorderSide, color: CGColor, thickness: CGFloat) {
        
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color
        
        switch side {
        case .Left:
            border.frame = CGRect(
                x: frame.minX,
                y: frame.minY,
                width: thickness,
                height: frame.height
            )
            break
        case .Right:
            border.frame = CGRect(
                x: frame.maxX,
                y: frame.minY,
                width: thickness,
                height: frame.height
            )
            break
        case .Top:
            border.frame = CGRect(
                x: frame.minX,
                y: frame.minY,
                width: frame.width,
                height: thickness
            )
            break
        case .Bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(
                x: frame.minX,
                y: frame.maxY,
                width: frame.width,
                height: thickness
            )
            break
        }
        
        layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

Now, we see two "print frame" outputs:

```
segmentedControl Frame in viewDidLoad(): (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
segmentedControl Frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews(): (0.0, 97.66666666666667, 393.0, 19.333333333333332)
```

Unfortunately, this is the result:

[image]

The blue layer is positioned **way below** the bottom of the stack view / labels.

That's happening because the extension is using `frame.maxY` -- which is `frame.origin.y + frame.size.height` -- and the frame's `origin.y` is `97.66666666666667` (it's top is below the navigation bar).

You *could* use the same `addBorder()` approach, by calling it after the views have been laid out (that is, after the frames have been set), and modifying the extension to use the view's `bounds` instead of `frame`:

```
    case .Bottom:
        border.frame = CGRect(
            x: bounds.minX,
            y: bounds.maxY,
            width: bounds.width,
            height: thickness
        )
        break
```

and we get this:

[image]

However... as should be obvious, this is really not a good approach. Worth noting also is that the `layer` appears ***outside the bounds of the view***. So, if you were to add a subview constrained to the bottom of `segmentedControl`, the top of **that** view would be covered by the 20-point tall "border" layer.

My guess is that you are also going to want to be able to tap the labels... possible you also want to move that "border" to show only under the selected label... etc.

Do some searching / exploring how to subclass `UIView` so it handles all of that by itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Is "subclass UIView" a literal term? Can I use that keyword to look for the stuff you mentioned above? Or if it's not much of a trouble, can you hook me up with some articles explaining this?

Comment: @Axel - yes... head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift subclass uiview`